# Error in Mysqlback up

Tags: c#, mysql

Input string was not in correct format.
there is a warning message upon clicking the button on the back-up.
I cannot post the screenshot because of my reputation here is the code:

```
private void btnBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string constring = "Server=localhost;Database=thesis;Uid=root;Pwd=;pooling=false; convert zero datetime=True";
                string file = "D:\\backup.sql";
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlBackup ba = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                    {
                        ba.ExportToFile(file);
                        MessageBox.Show("done");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

i got the error of input string was not in correct format up "ba.ExportToFile(file)"

Comment: Do you specify the password in your connection string? are all the ports etc open? Does mysql run on the localhost?

Comment: i have no password on my database, yes it run on my localhost, i'm using wampserver.

Comment: Could you explain where did you find the MySqlBackup class? If I am not in error this class doesn't exist in the standard Connector for NET

Comment: download dll for backup sir

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the values you are passing to your functions. If some function is accepting int values and you'll pass string to it. It'll through this exception.